# A: Use vivante GPU on IMX6 with 4.14 kernel

Tags: gpu, yocto, imx6, bsp

I am working on Phytec based custom board, While porting Phytec BSP from krogoth to thud, I am unable to use gpu based rendering.

Krogoth:

- Display -> imx-drm
- libegl provider -> imx-gpu-viv

Thud:

- Display -> imx-drm
- libegl provider -> mesa

I am using one GUI application which requires egl library. It is throwing below error

```
INFO   [0.747]:GLES 2.0: initialize native API
INFO   [0.748]:GLES 2.0: Initialize EGL display
WARN   [0.749]:eglGetDisplay: failed.

ERROR  [0.749]:Can't initialize the display
```

Please explain GPU driver relation with mesa and imx-gpu-viv and application to use it.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, but it seems that you are missing the kernel module imx-gpu-viv and/or didn't load it.

Comment: Is Phytec not following the mainline kernel in there BSP and you would like to use the linux-imx kernel?

Answer (score 1):

I recently passed from Pyro to Warrior on an iMX6 CPU, and I had some trouble with the GPU. The driver was not compiled at all, and the Gstreamer GPU plugins were not working. It finally worked with the following configuration:

I added to my local.conf (or machine.conf) the line:

```
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += " kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv"
```

I also added the GPU config on my kernel defconfig:

```
CONFIG_MXC_GPU_VIV=m
```

Hope it helps.